# How to add events to calendar on android device without using Intent

Tags: android, kotlin

I followed the instruction on https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/calendar-provider.html

Below are my codes.
I can get event ID after I run these codes, 
but I didn't see any change on Calendar on my device (pixel 3XL)
CALENDAR_ID is got by contentResolver.query(calendars, projection, null, null, null)

```
private fun addCalendarEvent() {
            var cr = context!!.contentResolver
            var values = ContentValues()

            val beginTime = Calendar.getInstance()
            beginTime.set(2019, 11, 1, 7, 30)
            var startMillis = beginTime.timeInMillis
            val endTime = Calendar.getInstance()
            endTime.set(2019, 11, 2, 8, 30)
            var endMillis = endTime.timeInMillis

            values.put(CalendarContract.Events.CALENDAR_ID, "8".toLong())
            values.put(CalendarContract.Events.HAS_ALARM, 1)
            values.put(CalendarContract.Events.DTSTART, startMillis)
            values.put(CalendarContract.Events.DTEND, endMillis)
            values.put(CalendarContract.Events.TITLE, "test")
            values.put(CalendarContract.Events.DESCRIPTION, "test class")

            values.put(CalendarContract.Events.EVENT_TIMEZONE, Calendar.getInstance().timeZone.id)
            var uri = cr.insert(asyncAdapter(CalendarContract.Events.CONTENT_URI,
                "abc@gmail.com","com.google"), values)
            val eventID = java.lang.Long.parseLong(uri.lastPathSegment)
            Toast.makeText(activity!!.applicationContext, "id: $eventID", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
}
```

```
fun asyncAdapter(uri: Uri, account: String, accountType: String): Uri {
    return uri.buildUpon()
        .appendQueryParameter(CalendarContract.CALLER_IS_SYNCADAPTER, "true")
        .appendQueryParameter(CalendarContract.Calendars.ACCOUNT_NAME, account)
        .appendQueryParameter(CalendarContract.Calendars.ACCOUNT_TYPE, accountType).build()
}
```

What I would like to do can be referred to an app called "TimeTree".
If I register in that app, it can add event and sync to OS calendar.

Comment: I've found my fault. Without using "fun asyncAdapter"
just use 「var uri = cr.insert(CalendarContract.Events.CONTENT_URI, values)」